# Rails 7 Engine Initializer Hook Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, hook, initializer, ruby-on-rails-7

trying to get my gem working in Rails 7. I have confirmed it works in Rails 6.1.4.1 (latest).

In my engine's engine.rb file I have this...

```
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    initializer "my_engine.include_controller" do |app|
      ActionController::Base.send :include, MyEngine::MyController
    end
  end
end
```

Upon server start or running a console I get...

`uninitialized constant MyEngine::MyController (NameError)`

I have the gem controllers in their namespaced directory and to reiterate this works in Rails 6.1.

I have also tried these variations with the same error...

```
ActionController::Base.include MyEngine::MyController
```

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller_base do
  include MyEngine::MyController
end
```

If I put the following in the main app's ApplicationController instead then it works...

```
include MyEngine::MyController
```

Does anyone have any insight to how these hooks need to be called or should I report this as a bug to the rails team?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? - I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the same issue by pushing the required files to the `autoload_once_paths` configuration. Here an example of a possible fix.

```rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyEngine

    config.autoload_once_paths << "#{root}/app/controllers"

    initializer "my_engine.include_controller" do |app|
      ActionController::Base.send :include, MyEngine::MyController
    end
  end
end
```

Sources:

- https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-once-paths
- https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/issues/305
- https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/lib/turbo/engine.rb